# How do I build a dog house for Dogmeat?

Tags: fallout-4

When I dismiss Dogmeat in Fallout 4 I have to search for him if I send him to a settlement. I would love to give him a place to chill and wondered if a constructed dog house would enable me to find him quickly? However I do not see the ability to do that in the workshop, so is this possible and if so how?  Thanks so much & sorry if this has been addressed before but I cannot find any info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's under **Decorations > Misc > Doghouse** for x3 Wood, x1 Steel

Your dog(s) will hang around one in a settlement you assign them to. Note that if there are several doghouses within the settlement border, dogs can choose randomly.

Comment: By the way, the dog may choose any doghouse to spawn at, so if you build one in one settlement, send your dog there and then you can't find him, he probably is at some other, hidden doghouse.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC I knew about that but did not make it clear in the answer - fixed.